# Media Player delays to start

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, media

My media player delays its start when kept idle for some time, also some time it does not play the audio.

Earlier I used `setDataSource()`, but this time I am using `create()`.

For reference this is the code I am using:

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = _context.getResources().openRawResourceFd(this._soundResource.get(this._toBePlayed));
        mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        afd.close();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.start();
            }
        });
        mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                mp.reset();
                mp.release();
            }
        });
        mp.prepareAsync();
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the delay problem for *start()*. I fixed it with ***mp.seekTo(0)*** in *onPrepared* like this:

```
mp.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener(){
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mp.seekTo(0);
        mp.start();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why would this fix the problem? The MediaPlayer defaults to 0, so all you are doing is adding an extra method call.

Comment: You are right, it defaults to 0, but still this fix worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I use a FileInputStream. You didn't set the *AudioStreamType*. Here is how I setup my MediaPlayer.

```
   public void setupMediaPlayer(){
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(tempFilePath);
        mp.setDataSource(fis.getFD());
        mp.prepare();
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

**tempFilePath** is the path to the file.

I also implement **setOnPreparedListener** in this class which makes your code a lot more readable in my opinion.

Also Great link to reference: [MediaPlayer State Diagram](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html)

Comment: For anyone finding this now, setAudioStreamType is now deprecate (as of API 26) and setAudioAttributes is prefered. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#setAudioAttributes(android.media.AudioAttributes)

Answer (score -3):

I think if you would change

```
mp.prepareAsync();
```

to

```
mp.prepare();
```

and put

```
mp.start();
```

after the *mp.prepare();* your code will work. Give it a try.

Comment: This does not solve the issue. Instead, this blocks the main thread. Very bad for UI/UX.